# Future return type in Scala

Tags: scala

I created some simple code in the Scala REPL like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
Future { println("Hello from the future") }
```

and noticed the output was this:

```
scala> Future { println("Hello from the future") }             
Hello from the future
res5: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1706a01b
```

Why is the value of the Future a Promise? I thought that a Promise contained a Future, not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

In Future API, `apply` (factory/constructor `Future[T](=> T)`) is specified to return a `Future[T]`. Beyonds that abstraction for asynchronous programming, it's implementation details specific to the `ExecutionContext` (not required to be known). Implementation can differ with another execution context.

Answer (score 0):

every `Future` has a corresponding `Promise`.The object you get back is a `DefaultPromise`, which implements both `Future` and `Promise`. However, this is an implementation detail.